# Android Wear OS Health Services - Sleep Detection

Tags: android, wear-os, androidx, android-wear-2.0

Is there any way to programmatically subscribe to sleep / awake events from within an app that uses Android Wear OS' Health Services?

The docs reference creating synthetic data for these events (see for [example here](https://developer.android.com/health-and-fitness/guides/health-services/simulated-data)), but I don't see docs for consuming these events.

I would like to develop a Wear OS App that can run code when the user falls "asleep".

Comment: Hi, do you have any updates here?